# Code splitting and SSR with react-native-web

Tags: server-side-rendering, code-splitting, react-native-web

Is anyone successfully code-splitting while SSR react-native-web? I can implement SSR and can code-split without SSR but haven't been able to do both at the same time

Answer (score 2):

You can try Next.js with react native web. It does both SSR and page based code splitting.

Here is an example repo:

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-react-native-web

Comment: so pages/ files are SSR streamed? Isn't this something only with app/ component at NextJS 13 was introduced? I mean yes it's a server component but is it a equivalent to SSR streamed app pages? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update: After some intense investigation, evaluation while trying out and comparing several existing solutions, I've found one, that I've decided to use at least in one app now.

Want to keep dynamic and offer a toolbox with many technologies to choose from in the end, but for now...

TAMAGUI !!!!
https://tamagui.dev/

I'm a NextJS fan and I've also embedded the framework into Next, however I think it's not really necessary to do so.

I'm going with the Expo variant described in this great video in portugues (subtitles if your portugues is "muy ruin":

https://youtu.be/ccEsZsDm430

I hope you enjoy as much as I do.